# Using Multiple Input_Method_Service in an App

Tags: android, service, keyboard, android-input-method

I have used InputMethodService in my ImageKeyboard app to send Images from keyboard.
I have repeated the same thing with my second app : EmojiKeyboard app to send Emojis from keyboard.

Now, I have to combine both the app with single one. So, I found in manifest as below : 
**in my EMOJIKEYBOARD app :**

```
    <service
        android:name=".EmojiKeyboardService"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
```

The another one is in my **IMAGEKEYBOARD app :**

```
 <service
        android:name=".service.ImageKeyboard"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_INPUT_METHOD">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.view.InputMethod" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.view.im"
            android:resource="@xml/method" />
    </service>
```

Now, here **@xml/method** for first app is like :

`<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />`

and for second is like :

```
<input-method xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:isDefault="false"
android:settingsActivity="com.myapp.MySettings"></input-method>
```

Here, it gives me  :

**Now,** I have confused that, How can I switch between this two ?

Any idea ? Because, I have to open two different layouts for keyboard i.e. switching between two services.

Hope for the best solution.Thanks.